# Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings

Tags: python, unicode

I have a function that removes punctuation from a list of strings:

```
def strip_punctuation(input):
    x = 0
    for word in input:
        input[x] = re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', "", input[x])
        x += 1
    return input
```

I recently modified my script to use Unicode strings so I could handle other non-Western characters. This function breaks when it encounters these special characters and just returns empty Unicode strings. How can I reliably remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings?

Comment: `strip_punctuation()` should accept strings instead of list of strings then if you need it you could `list_of_strings = map(strip_punctuation, list_of_strings)`

Comment: That might be a better way actually. I like your and F.C.'s implementations using unicode categories.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You could use `unicode.translate()` method:

```
import unicodedata
import sys

tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode)
                      if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.translate(tbl)
```

You could also use `r'\p{P}'` that is supported by [regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex as re

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return re.sub(ur"\p{P}+", "", text)
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting regex - this is _the_ way to go here. It would be worth noting that it's non-standard (yet) and has to be installed separately. Also, in py2, you need the pattern to be unicode (`ur".."`) to toggle unicode matching mode.

Comment: @thg435: I've added link to regex module and made the pattern unicode

Comment: @thg435 I agree regex is ideally the way to go. Unfortunately I need to keep my external modules to a minimum as I'm not the only user. I've gone with the former solution which is slow but it does work. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @acpigeon: I've moved `tbl` to the global scope to make it clear that it only needs to be generated once

Comment: @Pablo: why did you revert my Python 3 compatible edit?

Comment: @kermit666: my guess: the question has no explicit [tag:python-3.x] tag therefore the code should run on Python 2. Your edit breaks the code on Python 2.

Comment: @kermit666 Look at the guidelines for reviewing Suggested Edits: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/178187. Specifically, the second point in "Common reasons to Reject". I reviewed your edit, but when I tried to reject it, other users had already approved it. That's why I reverted it.

Comment: Fair enough. I added it as a new answer.

Comment: The `re` module (not `regex`) doesn't seem to support `\p{P}`, does it?

Comment: Hmm I didn't realize `regex` was a pypi module. Tanks!

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for this answer when all other answers were for string.

Comment: On py3.5, I get a syntax error for the regex based solution, `temp = regex.sub(ur"\p{P}+", "", s)` the little arrow is at the double quote after the `+`. Something I am missing here?

Comment: @posdef it is Python 2 code (read the very first comment). Drop `u''` prefix before `r''` on Python 3 or use `u"\\p{P}+"` (you have to escape the backlash manually in this case).

Comment: Note that the `regex` solution does not strip out `|`. Can anybody point out how to add it to the regex?

Comment: @DennisGolomazov: it is correct. `|` (U+007C) is a [Math Symbol: `\p{Sm}`](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=Sm), it is not a [Unicode punctuation](https://codepoints.net/search?gc=P). Perhaps, you want `\p{posix_punct}` (`[[:punct:]]`). Depending on your specific case, it might be simpler to specify characters that you want to keep. It might be a good separate question if you have a specific list of requirements (what to keep, what to remove).

Comment: @Mithril perhaps [my last comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066400/remove-punctuation-from-unicode-formatted-strings/11066687#comment68272124_11066687) applies to your case too.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Does that means I have to `text.translate(tbl)` then `re.sub` ? Anyway to merge them?

Comment: @Mithril no. These are different solutions. The point is: what Unicode standard thinks "what is punctuation" may differ from what POSIX thinks "what is punctuation". You can pick whatever definition you like or even construct your own. You can use either str.translate or the regex  module (but there is no point in mixing them).

Answer (score 28):

If you want to use J.F. Sebastian's solution in Python 3:

```
import unicodedata
import sys

tbl = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode)
                      if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P'))
def remove_punctuation(text):
    return text.translate(tbl)
```

Comment: `text.translate({i: None for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P')})` -- That's if you have to use it minimally (dict is on the order of 800 keys) but otherwise it's probably better to pre-generate the `dict`.

Answer (score 9):

You can iterate through the string using the `unicodedata` module's [`category`](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) function to determine if the character is punctuation.

For possible outputs of `category`, see unicode.org's doc on [General Category Values](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/tr44-4.html#General_Category_Values)

```
import unicodedata.category as cat
def strip_punctuation(word):
    return "".join(char for char in word if cat(char).startswith('P'))
filtered = [strip_punctuation(word) for word in input]
```

---

Additionally, make sure that you're handling encodings and types correctly. [This presentation](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: +1 for unipain link. I'm trying to implement this, but I'm getting "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" on the result[i] line. I'll keep messing around.

Comment: @acpigeon: For some reason I was thinking you could assign to lists in a sparse way without pre-populating it. Edited with a better approach.

Comment: There's a small but important bug in this answer: strip_punctuation actually does the opposite of what you intend, and will return *only* the punctuation, because you forgot a `not` in your comprehension. I would edit the answer to fix it, except "edits must be at least 6 characters."

Answer (score 8):

A little shorter version based on [Daenyth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066443/181337)

```
import unicodedata

def strip_punctuation(text):
    """
    >>> strip_punctuation(u'something')
    u'something'

    >>> strip_punctuation(u'something.,:else really')
    u'somethingelse really'
    """
    punctutation_cats = set(['Pc', 'Pd', 'Ps', 'Pe', 'Pi', 'Pf', 'Po'])
    return ''.join(x for x in text
                   if unicodedata.category(x) not in punctutation_cats)

input_data = [u'somehting', u'something, else', u'nothing.']
without_punctuation = map(strip_punctuation, input_data)
```

Comment: OP said `input_data` is a list of strings, not just one string. (Of course, you can just map your version over it)