# Python - regex tokenizer with conditions

Tags: python, token, nltk

I'm trying to remove punctuation while tokenizing a sentence in python but I have several "condtitions" where I want it to ignore tokenizing using punctuation. Some examples are when I see a URL, or email address or certain symbols without spaces next to them. Example:

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w']+")

tokenizer.tokenize("please help me ignore punctuation like . or , but at the same time don't ignore if it looks like a url i.e. google.com or google.co.uk. Sometimes I also want conditions where I see an equals sign between words such as myname=shecode")
```

Right now the output looks like

> ['please', 'help', 'me', 'ignore', 'punctuation', 'like', 'or', 'but',
>   'at', 'the', 'same', 'time', "don't", 'ignore', 'if', 'it', 'looks',
>   'like', 'a', 'url', 'i', 'e', 'google', 'com', 'or', 'google', 'co',
>   'uk', 'Sometimes', 'I', 'also', 'want', 'conditions', 'where', 'I',
>   'see', 'an', 'equals', 'sign', 'between', 'words', 'such', 'as',
>   'myname', 'shecode']

But what I really want it to look like is

> ['please', 'help', 'me', 'ignore', 'punctuation', 'like', 'or', 'but',
>   'at', 'the', 'same', 'time', "don't", 'ignore', 'if', 'it', 'looks',
>   'like', 'a', 'url', 'i', 'e', 'google.com', 'or', 'google.co.uk',
>   'Sometimes', 'I', 'also', 'want', 'conditions', 'where', 'I', 'see',
>   'an', 'equals', 'sign', 'between', 'words', 'such', 'as',
>   'myname=shecode']

Comment: Try using "from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize". I am not sure if it will solve your purpose. But try it once. Thanks.

Comment: You should a) pre-tokenize the input on spaces; b) check each piece to decide if it is a url or not; and c) handle urls and non-url tokens differently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the a more complex regex tokenize, e.g. TreebankTokenizer from `nltk.word_tokenize`, see [How do I tokenize a string sentence in NLTK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057945/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-sentence-in-nltk):

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> text ="please help me ignore punctuation like . or , but at the same time don't ignore if it looks like a url i.e. google.com or google.co.uk. Sometimes I also want conditions where I see an equals sign between words such as myname=shecode"
>>> word_tokenize(text)
['please', 'help', 'me', 'ignore', 'punctuation', 'like', '.', 'or', ',', 'but', 'at', 'the', 'same', 'time', 'do', "n't", 'ignore', 'if', 'it', 'looks', 'like', 'a', 'url', 'i.e', '.', 'google.com', 'or', 'google.co.uk', '.', 'Sometimes', 'I', 'also', 'want', 'conditions', 'where', 'I', 'see', 'an', 'equals', 'sign', 'between', 'words', 'such', 'as', 'myname=shecode']
```

And if you would like to remove the stopwords, see [Stopword removal with NLTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk)

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize

>>> stoplist = stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation)

>>> text ="please help me ignore punctuation like . or , but at the same time don't ignore if it looks like a url i.e. google.com or google.co.uk. Sometimes I also want conditions where I see an equals sign between words such as myname=shecode"

>>> word_tokenize(text)
['please', 'help', 'me', 'ignore', 'punctuation', 'like', '.', 'or', ',', 'but', 'at', 'the', 'same', 'time', 'do', "n't", 'ignore', 'if', 'it', 'looks', 'like', 'a', 'url', 'i.e', '.', 'google.com', 'or', 'google.co.uk', '.', 'Sometimes', 'I', 'also', 'want', 'conditions', 'where', 'I', 'see', 'an', 'equals', 'sign', 'between', 'words', 'such', 'as', 'myname=shecode']

>>> [token for token in word_tokenize(text) if token not in stoplist]
['please', 'help', 'ignore', 'punctuation', 'like', 'time', "n't", 'ignore', 'looks', 'like', 'url', 'i.e', 'google.com', 'google.co.uk', 'Sometimes', 'I', 'also', 'want', 'conditions', 'I', 'see', 'equals', 'sign', 'words', 'myname=shecode']
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to the following expression

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer("[\w+.]+")
```

In regex `.` means any character.

So in your code, it's splitting on `.` also. So the new regex will prevent the splitting on `.`

Comment: Hi, sometimes i want it to split on it though, it will be conditional. perhaps if we see a ".com" or .co." then we don't want it to be split, does that make sense?

Comment: in regex `.` means any character, except between bracket `[`and `]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, if it works for you.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
punct_list = ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']
s = "please help me ignore punctuation like . or , but at the same time don't ignore if it looks like a url i.e. google.com or google.co.uk. Sometimes I also want conditions where I see an equals sign between words such as myname=shecode"
print [i.strip("".join(punct_list)) for i in word_tokenize(s) if i not in punct_list]
```

Check this [How to remove punctuation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317458/how-to-remove-punctuation[Question][]) as well