# Remove selected punctuation from unicode strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, punctuation

I am working with a set of unicode strings and using the following piece of code (as shown in [Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066400/remove-punctuation-from-unicode-formatted-strings)):

```
import regex

def punc(text):
    return regex.sub(ur"\p{P}+", " ", text)
```

I wanted to go one step further and try to selectively keep certain punctuations. For example `-` need not be removed from the unicode string. What would be the best way to do that? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can negate the `\p{P}` with `\P{P}` then put it in a negated character class (`[^…]`) along with whatever characters you want to keep, like this:

```
return regex.sub(ur"[^\P{P}-]+", " ", text)
```

This will match one or more of any character in `\p{P}` except those that are also defined inside the character class.

Remember that `-` is a special character within a character class. If it doesn't appear at the start or end of the character class, you'll probably need to escape it.

---

Another solution would be to use a negative lookahead (`(?!…)`) or negative lookbehind (`(?<!…)`)

```
return regex.sub(ur"((?!-)\p{P})+", " ", text)

return regex.sub(ur"(\p{P}(?<!-))+", " ", text)
```

But for something like this I'd recommend the character class instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for this:

```
def punc(text):
    return regex.sub(ur"[^\P{P}-]+", " ", text)
```

The trick is to negate the character class (`[^a]` matches anything *except* `a`) and to use the negated Unicode properties:

- We replace `\p{P}` by `[^\P{P}]` - both behave exactly the same.
- Now we can add characters to the class that should *not* be matched: `[^\P{P}-]` matches any punctuation character except `-`.