# Most Common letter in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Completing an exercise to find the most common letter in a string, excluding punctuation and the result should be in lowercase. So in the example `"HHHHello World!!!!!!!!!!"` the result should be `"h"`.

What I have so far is:

```
text=input('Insert String: ')
def mwl(text):
    import string
    import collections
    for p in text:
        p.lower()
    for l in string.punctuation:
        for x in text:
            if x==l:
                text.replace(x,'')
    collist=collections.Counter(text).most_common(1)
    print(collist[0][0])

mwl(text)
```

I would appreciate your help to understand why:

1. The case is not remaining changed to lower in `text`
2. The punctuation is not being permanently removed from the `text` string

Comment: It should be `text = text.replace(x,'')` and p.lower() won't change the string as well.

Comment: Strings are *immutable*, i.e. cannot be changed in-place, so the string methods return *a new string object*. You need to assign that new object back to the appropriate name, e.g. `text = text.lower()`.

Comment: You should use a regex to have an result of 'h'/'H'

Comment: @jonrsharpe now I get it! thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = input('Insert String: ')

from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter
def mwl(text):
    st = set(punctuation)
    # remove all punctuation and make every letter lowercase
    filtered = (ch.lower() for ch in text if ch not in st)
    # make counter dict from remaining letters and return the most common
    return Counter(filtered).most_common()[0][0]
```

Or use str.translate to remove the punctuation :

```
from string import punctuation
from collections import Counter
def mwl(text):
    text = text.lower().translate(str.maketrans(" "*len(punctuation),punctuation))
    return Counter(text).most_common()[0][0]
```

Using your own code you need to reassign text to the updated string:

```
def mwl(text):
    import string
    import collections
    text = text.lower() 
    for l in string.punctuation:
        for x in text:
            if x == l:
                text = text.replace(x,'')
    collist=collections.Counter(text).most_common(1)
    print(collist[0][0])
```

Also instead of looping over the text in your code you could just use in:

```
for l in string.punctuation:
     if l in text:
        text = text.replace(l,'')
```

Comment: thanks @Padraic. I have also added 'alpha=''.join(sorted(filtered))
    alpha=alpha.replace("","")' - is this the best?

Comment: @Dom13, if you are using my `filtered` you don't need to replace, there will be no punctuation left,`if ch not in st` removes the punctuation so all you have to do is pass filtered to Counter.

Comment: should have clarified, was trying to strip all white space. Eventually figured 'text=''.join(text.split())'. thanks again.

Comment: ah ok, I see. No problem

Comment: your `.translate()`-based solution is incorrect (it returns `'!'` instead of `'h'`). Python 3 has different interface here compared to Python 2. Though your solution fails on Python 2 too.

Comment: `string.punctuation` doesn't take into account non-ascii punctuation. You should use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` for proper caseless comparison. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27886782/4279). `most_common(1)` can be much more efficient than `most_common()[0]` (`min()` vs. `sorted()`).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- Strings are immutable. This means that functions like `lower()` and `replace()` *return* the results and leave the original string as is. You need to assign that return value somewhere.
- `lower()` can operate on the entire string: `text = text.lower()`.

For some ideas on how to remove punctuation characters from a string, see [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: thanks NPE. will get there. the set(punctuation) solution by user below seems easiest. cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> my_string = "HHHHello World!!!!!!!!!!"
>>> Counter("".join(re.findall("[a-z]+",my_string.lower()))).most_common(1)
[('h', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First big issues is you never actually assign anything.

```
 p.lower()
```

just returns a lowercase version of p. It does not set p to the lowercase version. Should be

```
p = p.lower()
```

Same with the text.replace(x,''). It should be 
    text = text.replace(x,'')

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> tgt="HHHHello World!!!!!!!!!!" 
>>> Counter(c.lower() for c in tgt if c in ascii_letters).most_common(1)
[('h', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If input is ascii-only then you could use `bytes.translate()` to convert it to lowercase and remove punctuation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase, punctuation

table = b''.maketrans(ascii_uppercase.encode(), ascii_lowercase.encode())
def normalize_ascii(text, todelete=punctuation.encode()):
    return text.encode('ascii', 'strict').translate(table, todelete)

s = "HHHHello World!!!!!!!!!!"

count = [0]*256 # number of all possible bytes
for b in normalize_ascii(s): count[b] += 1 # count bytes
# print the most common byte
print(chr(max(range(len(count)), key=count.__getitem__)))
```

If you want to count letters in a non-ascii Unicode text then you could use [`.casefold()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) (proper caseless comparison) and [`remove_punctuation()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter
import regex # $ pip install regex

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return regex.sub(r"\p{P}+", "", text)

s = "HHHHello World!!!!!!!!!!"
no_punct = remove_punctuation(s)
characters = (c.casefold() for c in regex.findall(r'\X', no_punct))
print(Counter(characters).most_common(1)[0][0])
```

`r'\X'` regex is used to count user-perceived characters instead of mere Unicode codepoints.