# Eliminating series of .replace() calls in Python

Tags: python, string, syntax, code-cleanup

I'm working on a project that involves parsing pages of text. I've written the following function to remove certain punctuation from a word and convert it to lowercase:

```
def format_word(word):
    return word.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').replace('\"', '').lower()
```

Is there any way to combine all of the calls to .replace() into one? This looks rather ugly the way it is! The only way I can think of doing it is as follows:

```
def format_word(word):
    for punct in '.,\"':
        word.replace(punct, '')
    return word.lower()
```

Comment: unrelated: you don't need to escape `"` inside `'` string literals.

Comment: related: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279)

Comment: related: [Remove punctuation from Unicode formatted strings](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) if you want to remove characters:

In python 2.x:

```
>>> 'Hello, "world".'.translate(None, ',."')
'Hello world'
```

In python 3.x:

```
>>> 'Hello, "world".'.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, ',."')))
'Hello world'
```

Comment: upvote. You could also emulate `.lower()` in the same `.translate()` call.

Comment: [code example that shows how to use `translate()` to emulate `lower()` for ascii data](http://ideone.com/VpW59X)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [**`re` module**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for that

```
import re
>>> def format_word(word):
...     return re.sub(r'[,."]', "", word)
...
>>> print format_word('asdf.,"asdf')
asdfsdf
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `'` after your regular expression. It should be `r'[,."]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite close. If you don't only call `.replace()`, but as well use its result, you are done:

```
def format_word(word):
    for punct in '.,\"':
        word = word.replace(punct, '')
    return word.lower()
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question of avoiding multiple calls to `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using regular expressions:

```
re.sub("[.,\"]", "", "\"wo,rd.")
```