# remove punctuation from unicode: error

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I need to remove punctuation from a unicode string. I've read a few posts and the most recommended one was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/5374161).

I've implemented the following:

```
table = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P'))

def tokenize(message):
    message = unicode(message,'utf-8').lower()
    #print message
    message = remove_punctuation_unicode(message)
    return message

def remove_punctuation_unicode(string):
    return string.translate(table)
```

But when I run the code, this error pops up:

```
table = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(chr(i)).startswith('P'))
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

I can't quite figure it out what to do. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `unichr` instead of `chr`:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, unicodedata
>>> table = dict.fromkeys(i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)).startswith('P'))
>>>
```

Comment: @KrishanuKonar why did you use `chr` if [the post that you've linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/5374161) uses `unichr`?

Comment: honestly, I read it once, understood it and typed it myself, and I definitely typed it wrong, stupid mistake. my bad.