# Python for loop control variable accessed before declaration

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to understand the following line:

```
    "".join(char for char in input if not unicodedata.category(char).startswith('P'))
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066443/3818487

This code removes all unicode punctuation from input. I don't understand why it works. As far as I can tell, it just iterates over all characters in input ignoring the punctuation characters. How can it access char before it is declared in the for loop? I come from a java background, so this is very confusing to me.

Comment: You could read about 'List Comprehension' in python. That is what is being done here.

Comment: how is "removes all unicode punctuation" different from "iterates over all characters in input ignoring the punctuation characters" ? Those seem like the same final result to me.

Comment: Why did you change the identifier `word` in the linked answer to `input` here? `input()` is a built-in function, and shouldn't be masked like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comprehension would look more like the following, in regular code (using a list to store our non-punctuation characters).

```
#input is defined somewhere prior to the loop
output = []
for char in input:
    if not unicodedata.category(char).startswith('P'):
        output.append(char)
''.join(output)
```

Comprehensions iterate over the loop portion first, with the value being iterated over on the left.

Comment: Ah, so the char on the left is just a shorthand for storing the result of the iteration.

Comment: Not so much storing the result, but that the variable that is populated by the iteration (just like `char` in my example). Does that make sense? Edit: or did you mean "result" in that sense?

Comment: So, char acts as both a single character, and the list of all characters that were iterated through?

Comment: No, just a single character.