# How to remove all punctuation symbol from a list of unicode text using regex in python 3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode

I want to remove all punctuation symbol from my list, which is unicode text. When I executed the code as shown, there was no effect on the list. No symbol has been removed from the list. Though there was no syntax error displayed. I would like to mention that text is in the Gujarati language. I successfully removed the digits from the list.

```
....
....
filtered_words = [word for word in words if not re.search(r"[\P]+",word)]
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex here.

You can use `string.translate` like this:

```
filtered_words == [word for word in words if word == word.translate(None, string.punctuation)]
```

If you must use regex then use:

```
filtered_words == [word for word in words if not re.search(ur'[^\w\s]', word)]
```

[Check this Q&A or Unicode Punctuation detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066400/remove-punctuation-from-unicode-formatted-strings/11066687#11066687)