# How to remove special character from string in python if string contains script other than english

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a string which contains both English and Arabic and now I need to remove special characters.

I know there exist a regex solution:

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', mystring)
```

but this regex is also removing Arabic letters from the string.

Comment: By "special characters", do you mean everything non English/Arabic characters such as punctuations, symbols, Japanese characters, etc.? Do you mind providing an input and an expected output?

Comment: @ChickenFeet wrong language.

Comment: @ChickenFeet special characters means only punctuations and symbols.

Comment: I reopened this question because OP tried exactly what's mentioned in duplicate question. This is a different question/issue that needs to be addressed in another way. Please mention any true duplicate if you know so that we can close it properly. And, please use your privilege of closing questions properly and don't cause confusion to (future) users.

Comment: For those who are downvoting this issue,
I have looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843518/remove-all-special-characters-punctuation-and-spaces-from-string/5844618#5844618

but there was not any clarification about the answer given to this question and that answer was also for python2.
so I asked this question to clarify whether that solution is accepted in python3 or not.

Comment: @Kasramvd Please close it back again, the answer is there, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844618/3832970. It works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's not a valid reason to mark it as a duplicate I  found a more closer dup here tho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066400/remove-punctuation-from-unicode-formatted-strings/11066687

Comment: Closed. @Kasramvd ^ the solution in duplicate is cleaner than your answer.

Comment: @Kasramvd you've been awarded the gold badge. Use it and use it for *good* - *edit* the duplicates to add that question!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Clean is an abstract idea and it's relative. I also proposed two separates solutions which the first one is more optimized than what you call clean. Besides, next time you wanted to say clean elaborate on that and prove how this is cleaner. Is it cleaner only from your perspective or you mean everybody? and more importantly how? Also, cleanness is not always a factor please compare them by other factors such as memory usage, exec runtime, scalability, etc.

Comment: @Kasramvd the solution in the duplicate `'[\W_]+'` uses less substitutions when there are runs of non-word characters with `_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If underline (_) is not among your special characters, one clean way around this is using word characters modifier along with a unicode flag (In python-3 strings are unicodes and you don't need unicode flag).

```
In [10]: s = "#$&%NKGS&$@023489_7نسیتلبskdjfh3%-"

In [11]: re.sub('[^\w]+', '', s, flags=re.U)
Out[11]: 'NKGS023489_7نسیتلبskdjfh3'
```

If it's not you can also include that like following:

```
In [12]: re.sub('[^\w]+|_', '', s, flags=re.U)
Out[12]: 'NKGS0234897نسیتلبskdjfh3'
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)` is enough in Python 3 (`re.U` is implied). Actually, it is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844618/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. But still I think tat explicit is better than implicit. In this case both for the regex format and the unicode flag. But I'll still add that as a side note to the answer, thanks for note.