# How to replace a punctuation with a space in this code?

Tags: python, for-loop, punctuation

I have this code:

```
 def remove_punctuation(self,text):
        exclude = set(string.punctuation)
        a=''.join(ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude)
        return ''.join(c for c in a if not ud.category(c).startswith('P'))
```

First I would like to know what this does :

```
ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude
```

How is it possible to write a for loop like that?

second, I want to replace those punctuation let's say in a text like this :
"hello_there?my_friend!" with a space using the above code. How can I change that code to do that?

Comment: What does *"those punctuation"* mean?

Comment: You can read about [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to understand what the line `ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude` does. Basicly: it removes all chars that are NOT in `exclude`

Comment: @Austin I edited the post

Comment: That's not essentially a list comprehension (but a generator). Nevertheless, a read on it would help you understand what's going on. Between a list comprehension is more performant than generator comprehension with `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code:

```py
a = ''.join([ch for ch in text if ch not in exclude])
```

is equivalent to

```py
string_without_punctuation = ''
exclude = set(string.punctuation) # =set('!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~')
for character in text:
    if character not in exclude:
        string_without_punctuation += character
```

You could simply do this to replace the punctuation with spaces:

```py
string_without_punctuation = ''
exclude = set(string.punctuation) # =set('!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~')
for character in text:
    if character not in exclude:
        string_without_punctuation += character
    else:
        string_without_punctuation += ' '
```

Comment: this code doesn't remove unicode punctuation like the code I posted

Comment: You could change `if character not in exclude:` to `if character not in exclude and not ud.category(character).startswith('P'):`

Comment: still didn't fix it

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `str.translate` instead of manually rebuilding the string.  Make a lookup table mapping characters to the strings you want to replace them with.

```
trans = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation, ' '))

"hello_there?my_friend!".translate(trans)
# 'hello there my friend '
```

Comment: Does it also remove unicode punctuation? because the above code i posted does

Comment: @JohnSall No, I must have missed that.  `translate` can still be used, but you might have even more success with a regular expression.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066400/remove-punctuation-from-unicode-formatted-strings