# Why does my punctuation remover script skip over quotation marks?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python, and a project I've been assigned requires me to construct a script that can clear all punctuation from a text. This will later be used to count each word's frequency and convert it into a wordcloud. When trying to apply my script to an excerpt of the text (in this case Pride and Prejudice) the quotation marks seem to be skipped over even though they are included in my punctuation variable. What am I missing?

```
text = '''      “Already arisen?” repeated Mr. Bennet. “What, has she frightened
      away some of your lovers? Poor little Lizzy! But do not be cast
      down. Such squeamish youths as cannot bear to be connected with a
      little absurdity are not worth a regret. Come, let me see the
      list of pitiful fellows who have been kept aloof by Lydia’s
      folly.”'''
punctuation = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
text = text.lower()
clean = ""

for letter in text:
    if letter not in punctuation:
        clean += letter
print(clean)
```

As a result, I am returned the text with everything lowercase and without any punctuation except the quotation marks.

```
'''   “already arisen” repeated mr bennet “what has she frightened
      away some of your lovers poor little lizzy but do not be cast
      down such squeamish youths as cannot bear to be connected with a
      little absurdity are not worth a regret come let me see the
      list of pitiful fellows who have been kept aloof by lydia’s
      folly”'''
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

`“` and `”` are "smart quotes", not straight quotes (`"`). It's a completely different character. You can add them to your `punctuation` string if you like though.

To match and remove *all* Unicode forms of punctuation, you can use the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066687/364696), using [the third party `regex` module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex as re

def remove_punctuation(text):
    return re.sub(r"\p{P}+", "", text)
```