# algorithm for customer name verification

Tags: algorithm, names

Is there any algorithm or standard to verify customer names in different formats.

I mean,

- J. Smith
- John Smith
- John L. Smith
- J. Louis Smith
- John Louis S.

Could be the same person and should pass the validation.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like a particularly complex task, have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: "Unless you specify a particularly restrictive standard for what a name can be, this is likely to be a very difficult problem", said the person formerly known as "42" to the Hon. Rev. Dr. Jonathan Louis "Louie" Smith, Jr., D.D.S., Ph.D., M.Div.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer of [Figure out if a business name is very similar to another one - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400416/figure-out-if-a-business-name-is-very-similar-to-another-one-python) will definitely help you out as I myself have worked on a very similar approach to normalize names.

Note that a single standalone metric is not going to suffice. An ensemble approach will have to implemented taking character N Gram matching, Edit Distance and so on into account which ultimately returns a strength of the matched words. Devise a formula for calculating strength of your matched keywords and once your list of names is exhausted just re-run the Algorithm for the names/words which have a strength below a particular threshold set by you. This make the names then resonate to some other cluster of names where the match/strength value is more strong.

Also you will have to watch out for precision/recall trade-off. With the above approach I have seen that the precision is too good but the recall is not that great.