# Apply fuzzy string matching of two columns in two Pandas dataframes while preserving a similarity score and output a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have two data frames that I'm trying to merge, based on a primary & foreign key of company name. One data set has ~50,000 unique company names, the other one has about 5,000. Duplicate company names are possible within each list.

To that end, I've tried to follow along the first solution from [Figure out if a business name is very similar to another one - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400416/figure-out-if-a-business-name-is-very-similar-to-another-one-python). Here's an MWE:

```
mwe1 = pd.DataFrame({'company_name': ['Deloitte', 
                                      'PriceWaterhouseCoopers', 
                                      'KPMG',
                                      'Ernst & Young',
                                      'intentionall typo company XYZ'
                                     ],
                    'revenue': [100, 200, 300, 250, 400]
                   }
                  )

mwe2 = pd.DataFrame({'salesforce_name': ['Deloite',
                                         'PriceWaterhouseCooper'
                                        ],
                     'CEO': ['John', 'Jane']
                    }
                   )
```

I am trying to get the following code from [Figure out if a business name is very similar to another one - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400416/figure-out-if-a-business-name-is-very-similar-to-another-one-python) to work:

```
# token2frequency is just a word counter of all words in all names
# in the dataset
def sequence_uniqueness(seq, token2frequency):
    return sum(1/token2frequency(t)**0.5 for t in seq)

def name_similarity(a, b, token2frequency):
    a_tokens = set(a.split())
    b_tokens = set(b.split())
    a_uniq = sequence_uniqueness(a_tokens)
    b_uniq = sequence_uniqueness(b_tokens)
    return sequence_uniqueness(a.intersection(b))/(a_uniq * b_uniq) ** 0.5
```

How do I apply those two functions to produce a similarity score between each possible combination of `mwe1` and `mwe2`, then filter such that to the most probable matches?

For example, I'm looking for something like this (I'm just making up the scores in the `similarity_score` column:

```
company_name                   revenue    salesforce_name         CEO     similarity_score
Deloitte                       100        Deloite                 John    98
PriceWaterhouseCoopers         200        Deloite                 John    0
KPMG                           300        Deloite                 John    15
Ernst & Young                  250        Deloite                 John    10
intentionall typo company XYZ  400        Deloite                 John    2
Deloitte                       100        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    20
PriceWaterhouseCoopers         200        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    97
KPMG                           300        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    5
Ernst & Young                  250        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    7
intentionall typo company XYZ  400        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    3
```

I'm also open to better end-states, if you can think of one. Then, I'd filter that table above to get something like:

```
company_name                   revenue    salesforce_name         CEO     similarity_score
Deloitte                       100        Deloite                 John    98
PriceWaterhouseCoopers         200        PriceWaterhouseCooper   Jane    97
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
name_similarity(a = mwe1['company_name'], b = mwe2['salesforce_name'], token2frequency = 10)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I'm familiar with using lambda functions but not sure how to make it work when iterating through two columns in two Pandas data frames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I wrote using [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) should be close to what you need.

```
import difflib

import pandas as pd


class FuzzyMerge:
    """
    Works like pandas merge except merges on approximate matches.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.left = kwargs.get("left")
        self.right = kwargs.get("right")
        self.left_on = kwargs.get("left_on")
        self.right_on = kwargs.get("right_on")
        self.how = kwargs.get("how", "inner")
        self.cutoff = kwargs.get("cutoff", 0.8)

    def merge(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        temp = self.right.copy()
        temp[self.left_on] = [
            self.get_closest_match(x, self.left[self.left_on]) for x in temp[self.right_on]
        ]

        df = self.left.merge(temp, on=self.left_on, how=self.how)
        df["similarity_percent"] = df.apply(lambda x: self.similarity_score(x[self.left_on], x[self.right_on]), axis=1)

        return df

    def get_closest_match(self, left: pd.Series, right: pd.Series) -> str or None:
        matches = difflib.get_close_matches(left, right, cutoff=self.cutoff)

        return matches[0] if matches else None

    @staticmethod
    def similarity_score(left: pd.Series, right: pd.Series) -> int:
        return int(round(difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=left, b=right).ratio(), 2) * 100)
```

Call it with:

```
df = FuzzyMerge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on="column from df1", right_on="column from df2", how="inner", cutoff=0.8).merge()
```

Comment: The code worked pretty nicely in that it gave no errors, produces a Pandas dataframe and shares a similarity score. But right now, it gives 100 similarity score for: `ACADIA Pharmaceuticals Inc.` and `Shanghai Pharmaceuticals`; `Zuger Kantonalbank` and `Basler Kantonalbank`; `Zuger Kantonalbank` and `Luzerner Kantonalbank`

Comment: Another weird one: `Ynnovate` and `Novatek` have a similarity score of 100

Comment: odd Ynnovate and Novatek have a similarity score of 67 in a small test I just ran. When I find time I'll try to use your data.

Comment: Hm, I get your code to work with MWE dataframes in my original post. Interesting to note that the similarity score for all pairs/combinations is 100 on my actual dataset. Immediately, I checked the data type but it is indeed an "object" dtype in my actual dataset, like the MWE, so it's not that.